# How to find the ID of less common system sounds?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, system-sounds

Using this code you can play one of the more common system sounds:

```
let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1003
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID)
```

However, there are a lot of great sounds for your UI built into IOS that you find on these kind of paths:

```
/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/nano/Detent_Haptic.caf
```

So, how do you go about finding the ID of these sounds?

Comment: In iOS 13 you get the haptic sounds directly.

Comment: That's nice to know, but I want to play that specific sound for a touch on my UI. So I need access to it's ID number so I can play it, right?

Comment: No, that's what the new haptic sounds API gives you. Have you tried, like, watching any of the WWDC 2019 videos on this topic?

Comment: I can't use iOS 13... I have to support iOS 10+

Comment: Then you're out of luck.